# How can I make an angular-ui-router template accept two views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to understand how to use ui-router views. Here's what I have so far:

```
var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWord = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w',
    template: '<div ui-view ></div>',
    url: '/:wordId',
};

var rootSubjectsSubjectAdminWordsWordDelete = {
    name: 'r.s.s.a.w.w.delete',
    templateProvider: ['$templateCache', ($templateCache) => {
        return $templateCache.get('/app/admin/word/word.html');
    }],
    url: '/delete',
};
```

/app/admin/word/word.html

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="'/app/admin/word/wordData.html'"></ng-include>
    <ng-include src="'/app/admin/word/wordForms.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to remove the need for having word.html.

Is there a way that could make the template `'<div ui-view ></div>'` accept the two HTML 
files by somehow naming the views?

Comment: see this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Answer (score 0):

Here is per [UI Router Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). Basically inside where the views object is defined is where you'll name the view and point it to that view(see #1). After that router will take care of the rest.

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('report', {
    views: {
      //(#1)--here is the named router matching in the html.
      'filters': {
        templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
        controller: function($scope) {...controller stuff just
          for filters view...
        }
      },
      'tabledata': {
        templateUrl: 'report-table.html',
        controller: function($scope) {...controller stuff just
          for tabledata view...
        }
      },
      'graph': {
        templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',
        controller: function($scope) {...controller stuff just
          for graph view...
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<body>
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, If you have a few minutes can you show how I could do this using the question code just to make it a bit more clear as an answer to the solution.

Comment: @SamanthaJ sure, first what version of angular are you using?